# How to Differentiate MMS and SMS in android?

Tags: android, mms

How to Differentiate MMS and SMS via `MMS/SMS listeners` in Android? Because I got SMS counts as in MMS counts?

I am calculating Total MMS as using following code.

```
Uri mmsInboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/inbox");
Uri mmsSentUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/sent");

Cursor mmsInboxCursor = getContentResolver().
                         query(mmsInboxUri ,new String[] {"_id"},  null, null);
Cursor mmsSentCursor = getContentResolver().
                         query(mmsSentUri ,new String[] {"_id"}, null, null);
int mmsCount = mmsInboxCursor.getCount() + mmsSentCursor.getCount();
```

Comment: I tried your exact same code, and got the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the column `ct_t`. If it's a MMS it should be equal to `application/vnd.vap_multipart.related`.

Comment: I also use the above code but not get the result Pleas anybody can help me?